# What is the iPhone advertising in its BLE manufacturer data?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

Running a BLE scan program, iPhones are all around, and they all emit BLE advertisement packets.

The manufacturer data's company ID identifies them as Apple devices, and contains some data afterwards. For example:

- `10020B00`
- `090603060A000CA9`
- `10020100`
- `10020A40`
- `0C0E009828802D1074AA12BF25EA7FFE`

What is this data and how can it be interpreted?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but here it is:

example for 10020B00

First byte: 10 is the data type

Second byte is the number of byte remaining AFTER THIS BYTE for this data (here 02)

Others bytes are the datas, here 0B and 00  (the 2 bytes as seen just before)